# Having errors while making a chatbot using react and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, chatbot

I have been making this chatbot with the help of a tutorial course on udemy.
Till now I have made a dialogflow agent and have created intents and everything and with the help of different modules I have also setup the server side of the app. Now while I was making the chatbot module of the website I encountered 5 errors.

This is my code for setupProxy.js file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
     
/*module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware("/api/*", { target: "http://localhost:5000"}));
}*/

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/api/*', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:5000', changeOrigin: true}));
  };
```

This is my code for the Chatbot.js file :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios/index';
import Message from './Message';

class Chatbot extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this._handleInputKeyPress = this._handleInputKeyPress.bind(this);

        this.state = {
             messages: []
        }
    }
    async df_text_query(text){
        let says = {
            speaks: 'me',
            msg: {
                text: {
                    text: text
                }
            }
        };
        this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, says]});
        const res = await axios.post('/api/df_text_query', {text});

        for (let msg of res.data[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages){
            says = {
                speaks: 'bot',
                msg: msg
            };
            this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, says]});
        }
    }

    async df_event_query(event){

        const res = await axios.post('/api/df_event_query', {event});

        for (let msg of res.data[0].queryResult.fulfillmentMessages){      /*let msg of res.data.fulfillmentMessages*/
            let says = {
                speaks: 'me',
                msg: msg
            };
            this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, says]});
        }
    }
     
    componentDidMount(){
        this.df_event_query('Welcome');
    }

    renderMessages(stateMessages){
        if (stateMessages){
            return stateMessages.map((message, i) =>{
                return <Message key={i} speaks={message.speaks} text={message.msg.text.text}/>;
            });
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    _handleInputKeyPress(e){
        if(e.key === 'Enter'){
            this.df_text_query(e.target.value);
            e.target.value = '';
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div style = {{ height: 400, width: 400, float: 'right' }}>
                <div id = "chatbot" style = {{height: '100%', width: '100%', overflow: 'auto'}}>
                    <h2>Admissa</h2>
                    {this.renderMessages(this.state.messages)}
                    <input type = "text" onKeyPress = {this._handleInputKeyPress} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
   
export default Chatbot;
```

This is the code for the Message.js file:

```
import React from 'react';

const Message = (props) => {
    <div className="col s12 m8 offset-m2 offset-13">
        <div className="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
            <div className="row valign-wrapper">
                {props.speaks ==='bot' &&
                <div className="col s2">
                <a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red">{props.speaks}</a>
                </div>
                }
                <div className="col s10">
                    <span className="black-text">
                        {props.text}
                    </span>
                </div>
                {props.speaks ==='me' &&
                <div className="col s2">
                <a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red">{props.speaks}</a>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
};

export default Message;
```

This is my main app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './Header';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import AboutUs from './pages/AboutUs';
import Chatbot from './chatbot/Chatbot';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className = "container">
                    <Header/>
                    <Route exact path = "/home" component = { Home }/>
                    <Route exact path = "/aboutus" component = { AboutUs } />
                    <Chatbot/>
                </div>           
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

And when i am running this using `npm run dev` from my command prompt these are the following errors which I am getting:

[5 errors after running the server for the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq7wO.png)

Comment: Take it from the top: As the first error indicates, your Message component isn't **returning** anything. Compare Message.js to app.js, which is returning its JSX.

Comment: This render() function is in my App.js file and Message.js file is not returning directly anything....and as far as I have matched both the files from the lecture in the course they both are exactly same as directed.
Can you please help and elaborate more.

Comment: Your Message() component must return its JSX:
`const Message = (props) => {
    return (
        // JSX...
    )
}`

Comment: @Ryan Thanks this thing worked for me but still my bot is not responding to me with the reply messages, as in I am only able to see my messages and not the responses and am having still some errors like :

```Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    createError     createError.js:16
    settle              settle.js:17
    handleLoad    xhr.js:62

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    createError    createError.js:16
    settle             settle.js:17
    handleLoad   xhr.js:62```

Answer (score 0):

I've been following the same course as you, and I tested your codes. I solved it by changing the curly braces to brackets. Hope this helps!

Yours:

```
const Message = (props) => {...};
```

What should've been:

```
const Message = (props) => (...);
```